# xsl sort not sorting?

Tags: xml, xslt

**lecturer.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Lecturer Information</title>
            </head>
            <body>  

                <table border="1">

                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Teaching</th>
                        <th>Research</th>
                    </tr>

                    <xsl:for-each select="lecturers/lecturer">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="name">
                                     <xsl:sort select="@last" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
                                </xsl:apply-templates>
                            </td>
                            <td><xsl:apply-templates select="teaching/course" /></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="research"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                </table>

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Templates HERE -->
    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="@title"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@first"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@last"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="teaching/course">
        <xsl:for-each select=".">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(. , '(',@code, ')')"/>  <br />
            <!-- <xsl:value-of select="."/> (<xsl:value-of select="@code"/>) -->
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**lecturer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="lecturer.xsl" ?>

<!DOCTYPE lecturers [

<!ELEMENT lecturers (lecturer+)>
<!ELEMENT lecturer (name, teaching, research)>

 <!-- Element name must contain attribute title, first and last -->
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST name
  title CDATA #REQUIRED
  first CDATA #REQUIRED
  last CDATA #REQUIRED
>

<!-- Teaching can have more than one course-->
<!ELEMENT teaching (course+)>

<!ELEMENT course (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST course
    code CDATA #REQUIRED
>

<!ELEMENT research (#PCDATA)>

]>
<lecturers>
    <lecturer>
        <name title="Professor" first="Peter" last="Quirk"/>
        <teaching>
                <course code="CO3070">XML and the Web</course>
                <course code="CO3300">Web Server Architectures</course>
        </teaching>
        <research>
                The application of Web protocols to Biology
        </research>
    </lecturer>
    <lecturer>
        <name title="Mr" last="Abdi" first="Ahmet"/>
        <teaching>
                <course code="CO1337">Ahmet's Course</course>
        </teaching>
        <research>
                The Best Research In the world.
        </research>
    </lecturer>
</lecturers>
```

this part of the xsl seems to not be sorting

```
<xsl:sort select="@last" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
```

Comment: Showing expected output vs. actual output would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `<xsl:sort>` element as a child of `<xsl:apply-templates select="name">`, but you don't need any sorting there because there is only one name in the given context.

Instead, you need to make `<xsl:sort>` a child of the `<xsl:for-each>`:

```
<xsl:sort select="name/@last" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
```

Make sure you change the `select` attribute as shown so that the sort will be able to find the last name from the context of the `<lecturer>` element.

Comment: @ahmet: You're welcome. Please "accept" Matthew's answer instead of mine... he answered first, and he needs the points more than I do.

Comment: +1 for the good answer and for being a nice and generous person. +1 for Matthew, too.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the line

```
<xsl:sort select="name/@last" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
```

needs to be right under the `for-each` statement

```
<xsl:for-each select="lecturers/lecturer">
```

That should sort all of your lecturer's by last name.

Comment: +1 yes, except don't forget the change of context! So the sort select attribute needs to be adjusted.

Comment: @LarsH Right. I spaced that off. I'll update my answer even though it will end up matching yours now. :P